# Linux NodeJS global NPM package ":No such file or directory"

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, npm

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and have installed `nodejs` and `npm` with:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
```

Then I made a symlink to enable packages to use the `node` interpreter (instead of `nodejs`):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node
```

I installed `coffee-script` (for testing purposes) and my own package, `mangarack`, with:

```
sudo npm -g install coffee-script mangarack
```

When I run `coffee` (part of `coffee-script`), that package will run fine. If I run `mangarack`, I will get:

```
: No such file or directory.
```

I have the following in my `package.json`:

```
"bin": {
  "mangarack": "./bin/mangarack"
},
```

And that file contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

require('../lib/cli/index');
```

I looked at how `coffee-script` did it and it seems like my `require` statement is absolutely wrong, so I replaced that with a `console.log` statement to see if the file would actually run in `node`. It doesn't. What did I miss or miss-configure to enable Linux-based machines to run this package?

Full source code references:

- npm: https://www.npmjs.org/package/mangarack
- git: https://github.com/Deathspike/mangarack.js

Comment: If your editor inserts carriage returns, well, you should really switch to a real one. Or find where to change the behaviour.

Comment: Indeed, I apparently should switch to a real one. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is the file `bin/mangarack` uses carriage return, which causes error in linux environment. see what I got:

```
$ mangarack --help
env: node\r: No such file or directory

$ head -n 1 `which mangarack` | hexdump
0000000 23 21 2f 75 73 72 2f 62 69 6e 2f 65 6e 76 20 6e
0000010 6f 64 65 0d 0a
0000015
```

Notice the character `\r`(`0d` in hex mode) after `node`. you should remove it.

Solution: setup your project with `$ git config core.autocrlf` then commit changes afterwards. see https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/

the expected result after fix should be:

```
$ head -n 1 `which mangarack` | hexdump
0000000 23 21 2f 75 73 72 2f 62 69 6e 2f 65 6e 76 20 6e
0000010 6f 64 65 0a
0000015
```

Comment: That's it! Windows machines will, by default, use \r\n as a line feed. When you commit to Git, it's all good and dandy because of the Git setting that usually commits Unix style line feeds. If you publish to npm, then you're zipping up and sending the files and thus get \r\n published. Thanks!

Comment: This is so difficult to understand from the feedback given by node, thanks for clarifying it for me.